# Changing check box automatically changes the database record

Tags: php, ajax

in my database I have the filed status which is boolean type,

thank I have a connection to the database

```
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cursos"))
{
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

and displaying the status of this field with checkboxes,

```
 <?php if($row['status'] == 1) { 
    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox' checked='checked' name ='complete' value= '1'/>"."</td>";
}else
{
    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox'  name ='incomplete' value= '0'/>"."</td>";
}
?>
```

So what I need to do is, once I check or uncheck any of thoose check boxes, the database field to be canged automatically withoud the need of submit button.

**Okay I did edited my code to what you suggested and it s working now, here is the new code:**

Ajax Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.checkboxtest').change(function(){
    if( $('.checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = '1';}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = '0';}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){alert(textStatus);})
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>
```

the html code is:

```
<?php if($row['status'] == 1) { 
    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox' class='checkboxtest' checked='checked' name ='complete' value= '1'/>"."</td>";
}else
{
    echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox' class='checkboxtest' name ='incomplete' value= '0'/>"."</td>";
}
?>
```

and the php backend code is:

```
<?php
$checkboxstatus = $_POST['checkboxstatus'];

$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "name";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " UPDATE cursos
           SET status = '$checkboxstatus'
           WHERE id = '12'";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh the only way to do this is with AJAX, if you don't mind the page refreshing then you can use javascript to auto-submit the form when the checkbox state is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob warning.

This is an interesting question for me, because I'll most-likely need to do it over the next few months, so I thought I take an hour and give it a shot.

Here is the html (boring):

```
<table class="centerme">
<tr>
<td>First Checkbox:<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxtest"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#checkboxtest').change(function(){
    if( $('#checkboxtest').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = "YES";}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = "NO";}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){alert(textStatus);})
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>
```

Here is the backend php:

```
<?php
$checkboxstatus = $_POST['checkboxstatus'];

$host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$user = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
$password = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
$dbname = "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " UPDATE testtable
           SET lastname = '$checkboxstatus'
           WHERE localid = '158' ";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");
?>
```

When I uploaded it to my site, it seems to work (get an error message that I haven't figured out yet, but the db changes (checked it with MySQL Workbench).

You could probably get away with just a $().POST, but I'm used to $ajax.

It would be interesting to get some comments from the experts.

PS - found the error - I should not have included the dataType in the ajax query.

Works great now!

Woohoo!

Comment: Hi you have it select only one check box  WHERE localid = '158' ";
what about if the checkboxes are coming from sql dump, where the declaration of the WHERE should be = $row['id'] how this can be achived ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response. I did this code just as an example of a single checkbox - a "proof of concept" for me. But you could take the same concepts and use them for multiple checkboxes. So you will have a series of checkboxes, and each one will have an id, and each one will have it's own little javascript subroutine that will run with a "click". I'll bet you could figure our a way to use just one PHP script and perhaps just one javascript routine to address all of the boxes. I'll think about it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input onclick="updateDatabase(this);" />`

then in your javascript "updateDatabase" execute an ajax request to your php file that handles modifying the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful article regarding the use of ajax with php.

[PHP Using AJAX INSERT INTO MYSQL](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/195823-php-using-ajax-insert-into-mysql/)

Here's how they done it:

```
var func = '';
var param = '';
var elem = '';

function myeval()
{
    var evalthis = func+'('+param+')';
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4)
    {
        eval(evalthis);
    }
}

function getHTTPObject()
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject) 
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else 
    {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
        return null;
    }
}

function changesomething(myphpurl, setchangedstate)
{
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) 
    {
        httpObject.open("GET", myphpurl);
        httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setchangedstate;
    } else {
        alert("oops!");
    }
}


function display_results(x)
{
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4)
    {
        alert("This is a parameter passed through the ajax process to this function: "+x);
        document.getElementById('some_element').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
    }
}

function add_info(x)
{
    var myurl = 'some_php_file.php?SomeKey='+x;
    func = 'display_results';
    param = x; // or some other value!
    changesomething(myurl,'myeval');
}
```